# Executing code before isotope relayouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I want an item to span over the hole container area so that when the window resizes my item does that to. There is a "onLayout"-callback that has everything i need except it executes to late. here is what i want to do.

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.puff',
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    itemPositionDataEnabled: true,
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: columnWidth
    },
    onLayout: function ($elems, instance) {
        $spanningItem.width(this.width()-20);
    }
});
```

[And a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBenjaminsson/pk29D/4/)